# EXCEL - Remove password

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove password from an Excel Document](https://superuser.com/questions/58263/remove-password-from-an-excel-document)

Hi,
I have an .xls file. I do not remember the password and hence I am not able to open the same. How do I remove the password. If I can't recover also thats fine ?

Answer (score 0):

There are tools that do this, for example this one http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/how-to-remove-crack-or-break-a-forgotten-excel-xls-password/

Have not tried it myself. If it works will probably depend on how long / strong your passord was.

Comment: Not of much help. The spreadsheet was created using 2007 version

Answer (score 0):

I afraid with 2007 version the encryption is sufficiently strong to be practically unbreakable. Unless you remember your password, consider the file to be lost.

To learn more about 2007 encryption see http://www.oraxcel.com/projects/encoffice/help/How_safe_is_Word_2007_encryption.html

There is an utility which can recover the password if you have selected it badly and is weak:

http://lastbit.com/office2007password.asp

For a middle strength password you might see success with their cloud service.

Note: It the password recovery is successful, you will need to pay for the recovery to be actually able to open the file.