# Recover xlsx password

Tags: microsoft-excel, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove password from an Excel Document](https://superuser.com/questions/58263/remove-password-from-an-excel-document)

Is there any way to recover a lost password for xlsx files? Legal solutions only please. I created the file months ago when things were crazy and I cannot remember the password.

If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: From my experience: No, not for xlsx. For xls I think there were some options but not since the 'x' was added

Answer (score 0):

this will do sheet recovery:

http://windows-passwordrecovery.blogspot.com/2011/08/recover-ms-excel-2007-password-without.html

and this will remove protection:

http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/hack-into-a-protected-excel-2007-or-2010-workbook/

but if you need it on opening, then you may have to purchase something.  This version claims to give you the first 3 characters as it's demo:

http://www.excelpasswordcracker.com/

This may be enough to remind you what the password is

Comment: Not clear why you posted the first two links as they don't address the question.

Comment: @brettdj, there are many places a password can be set. I gave answers for the most common places

Comment: Yes but the question is reasonably clear that the password applies to the file. Not sheet protection, or VBA modules within the file ... granted there is a smidgeon of uncertainty

Comment: @brettdj - You're assuming that Ken knows the difference between a "file" password and a "sheet"/"workbook" password. I would ask the original poster for clarification as people often get these things confused.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help and yes I do know the difference between a file password and a sheet password. I didn't really think there was any easy way to recover the password but I thought I'd ask anyway. I'll just have to recreate the file no biggie just a waste of time.

Comment: Have you actually tried any of those tools you are linking to? They all seem more than fishy and are usually of the type we delete as spam from 1-rep users.

Comment: @slhck, the first two involve editing the file as a zip, so no *fishy* software involved. The password recovery one I have used (and the trial gave me enough of the password to remind me what I had used), but there are many password recovery programs out there. They are simply a frontend to a brute force attack to try to open a passworded zip. One I have seen (but not used) claims to use the GPU instead of the CPU to get better throughput. I will edit the link to the actual publisher, rather than the reseller

Comment: @Stepan1010 Yes. I did. But a) I though this was clear enough b) indeed that was the case.

Comment: Tried to do the first two involving renaming and extracting but that did not work. I made a copy and renamed the copy but errored when I tried to extract or view contents.

Comment: The brute force attempt ran for 4 hours and failed. Oh and it corrupted my file.

Comment: SPYWARE WARNING - The Excel Password Cracker set off my TrendMicro as it contains HKTL_PASSVIEW. Might be best to run within a VM. http://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/threat-encyclopedia/malware/hktl_passview